# Restoring original baseband to iPhone 3G 4.2.1 with iPad baseband

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, unlock

A friend of mine bought an iPhone 3G from some T-Mobile cell phone vendor. The vendor had installed a custom 4.2.1 ipsw with the iPad baseband because iPhone 3G's wasn't unlockable at the time. That was great at first, but then my friend tried to restore the iPhone through iTunes. Because of the baseband, in the middle of the restore (the bar on the iPhone was partially filled) iTunes would vomit an error and axe the whole process, essentially bricking the device. He usually takes his computer issues to me, so I managed to fix the issue by reading forums and by finding an ipsw online with iPad's baseband.

That iPhone's been working for a while now, but if this happens again, is there a way I can revert from the iPad baseband so he can restore through iTunes without my intervention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot restore the baseband. Upgrading to iPad baseband 6.15.00 is permanent (unless for some magical reason Apple wanted to come out with new firmware for the iPhone 3G/3GS that miraculously contained a baseband higher than 6.15.00). What you have to do is use [redsn0w](http://blog.iphone-dev.org/tagged/redsn0w) to remove the baseband from an `.ipsw` file (the iOS firmware from Apple) if you want to upgrade/restore. There's an excellent tutorial on how to do that [here](http://iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=18932). Note that you it will always need to be JailBroken, too (which that tutorial has you do), because iTunes will not verify your `.ipsw` under these circumstances (even if you try to load on the modified firmware without JailBreaking and then taking it into iTunes to complete the verification/activation (believe me, I've tried)).

Answer (score 1):

i had the same exact issue yesterday and thank god for Everythingapplepro on Youtube. The answer to fix your bricked iphone 3G is here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0I1dNq5g3Kk

After getting your iphone 3g up and running again, you have the option to downgrade your baseband if you meet the following requirements that are outlined in his other video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2UJfyVcDEWg

His videos are AMAZING!

Comment: It's *possible* that you *could* have that low of a bootloader, but it's very unlikely. It's a good option to consider if you're lucky enough to meet the requirements, though. Also, Fuzzyband hasn't been updated for two years, so the likeliness of it working for a device running iOS 4 is **very** low.

Comment: I can vouch for the fact that fuzzyband still works. I was lucky enough to meet the requirements as outlined in the video, and fuzzyband was able to successully downgrade my baseband and subsequently I was able to unlock my iphone 3g using ultrasn0w. i'm a very happy person!

Answer (score 0):

By now it is possible to **down**-grade your baseband from the iPad's 06.15 to 05.13.04 (un-lockable) thanks to the great work of the iPhone Dev Team:

> The iPhone Dev Team is happy to announce a baseband downgrade option in redsn0w for those who are using the iPad’s 06.15 baseband on the iPhone3G or iPhone3GS.
>
> Typically you’d have the 06.15 baseband if you unlock with ultrasn0w but updated your iPhone baseband past 05.13.04.  With this new capability, you can now downgrade specifically from 06.15 to 05.13.04 (even if you never had 05.13.04 on that device before).  This gives you the best of both worlds: ultrasn0w compatibility and a normal iPhone baseband with full GPS and the ability to use stock IPSWs again.

See [this post](http://blog.iphone-dev.org/post/25350690843/0615-fun) on their blog.